# How to stop (Force-Stop) other app programmatically Android?

Tags: android, kill

I'm trying to stop others applications programmatically and i saw many samples, but didn't work.

```
try {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    Process.killProcess(p.pid);
    Process.sendSignal(p.pid, Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
    manager.killBackgroundProcesses(p.getPackageName());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It didn't work, but i saw other way to do it over adb and it work.

```
adb shell am force-stop packagename
```

Could anyone tell me if is it possible to force-stop an application ?

Answer (score 1):

If device rooted or application signed with system signature, its possible. Otherwise you will get an permission error when run this code.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("am force-stop packagename");
```

Comment: which permission are need , can u give any sample links

Comment: @earthling it needs root permission. it'll only work if the device is rooted